# ios app lags and freezing iphone 6s/7/8 in iOS 13

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, ios13, xcode11

We have an iOS native app developed with Objective C and using auto-layout with Storyboard for UIs.

- It is working fine in iOS 12.4.1 in all devices and it is not
  working now in the iOS 13 on iPhone 6s/7/8 only.
- Only this screen size has the issue.
- Other than that all other iphone screens are supporting upto to
  iPhone 11 Pro Max.
- And this issue is not there in the iPhone 6s/7/8 simulators. Only in
  the real device.
- When it is installed on iPhone 7 and run the app it lags very much
  and freeze the app occasionally, I have to close it, But the iphone is also gets laggy.

I am not getting any errors.

I thought this is layout issue, so I've Removed constraints of all first showing screens and re-added the constraints. And tried to debug with XCode Instruments to test performance but that didnt show me any issue also(I am not much familiar with using XCode Instruments).

I am stuck with this issue for several days. 
And I couldnt find anyone having the same issue.

I appreciate any help regarding this.
What could cause this?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue except that it's in the simulator. I get a freeze on screen update only in 6s/7/8 Plus, in simulator, Xcode 11, iOS 13. If I use the iOS 12 simulator, no problem. Other simulator sizes, no problem.

Comment: the cause for this issue may be constraints issue on your storyboard. check the log to find some trace and try to track from there. The issue with my app was Firebase analytics pod which was outdated. I was not sure how that fixed it, but removing the outdated pod and reinstalling and fixing the code, fixed that freezing issue for me.

Comment: Yes, it seems to have been my `layoutSubviews` code, which amounts to the same thing. I don’t understand how the problem could exist only on certain simulators but I thing I’ve fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: By the way you should answer your own question and accept your own answer, to help others and close out this question now that you’ve solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue and found out that *SearchDisplayController* which is deprecated, was being used in the code and storyboard as well. That was causing my app to crash on real device, but not on simulator with iOS 13.1.2. After removing the SearchDisplayController, things worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found out that the issue was with Firebase Analytics module and disabling that module fixed the issue for me.

Comment: @JanithGanewatta how did you disable the firebase analytics?